# How to use another column as X axis label when you plot pivot table in excel?

Tags: excel, plot, pivot-table, pivot-chart

[image]

I want to display Q2 2012, Q3 2013 instead of the auto generated labels of "sum of Apr to Jun 2012". But it's impossible to Edit the horizontal Axis labels here because this graph is generated by a pivot table. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Just Edit the column in pivot table, change "Sum of Apr to Jun 2012" to "Q2 2012".(hard code). Dumb but it works!